# How to stop winkey from closing keepass?

Tags: keepass

I'm an `awesomWM` user and use the winkey (between Ctrl and Alt) a lot. The problem is that for some reason pressing it closes `keepass` gui. I checked the options but I can't find a shortcut panel that contains that. Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in mono.

see https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/bugs/1545/#1618

You need to call mono with --verify-all, so edit /usr/lib/keepass to read:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec mono --verify-all /usr/share/keepass/KeePass.exe "$@"
```